# Android Open GL ES z-buffer not working on GL_POINTS(?)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

I'm beginning to think the z-buffer in GL ES (Android) doesn't work on GL_POINTS(?) but I cant find anything in the docs.

Im looking to make a cube primative out of points and render them to a scene using the Z buffer - I have a similar class (Triangle) which renders and does use the z-buffer?

PS: I know my code is messy (I'm getting annoyed with this) I've had a bit of a tidy to post this.

Code listed bellow:

```
class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

private final String vertexShaderCode =
        "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
        "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
        "uniform float vSpatical;" +
        "uniform vec3 vCamPos;" +
        "float vDistance;" +
        "float vDisX;" +
        "float vDisY;" +
        "float vDisZ;" +
        "float vA;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;" +
                "  vDisX = vCamPos.x-vPosition.x;" +
                "  vDisY = vCamPos.y-vPosition.y;" +
                "  vDisZ = vCamPos.z-vPosition.z;" +
                "  vA = 3.14159265359 * (vSpatical*vSpatical);" +
                "  vDistance = sqrt((vDisX*vDisX) + (vDisY*vDisY) + (vDisZ*vDisZ));" +
                "  gl_PointSize = 1.0 * vA / (vDistance*vDistance);" +
                "}";

private final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "precision mediump float;" +
                "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                "void main() {" +
                "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                "}";

private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
float[] mCamPos = {0f, 0f, 6f};

Triangle mTriangle;
Cube mCube;
int mProgram;
float mAngle = 0;

@Override
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 unused, EGLConfig config) {
    // Set the background frame color
    int vertexShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShaderCode);
    int fragmentShader = loadShader(GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShaderCode);
    mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);
    GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader);
    GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    mTriangle = new Triangle();
    mCube = new Cube();

    GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

    GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
    GLES20.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GLES20.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
    GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    GLES20.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
    GLES10.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);

}

@Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {
    float[] scratch = new float[16];

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, mCamPos[0], mCamPos[1], mCamPos[2], 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);


    Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, mAngle, 0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    mAngle += 0.09f;

    Matrix.multiplyMM(scratch, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

    mTriangle.draw(mProgram, scratch);
    mCube.draw(mProgram, scratch, mCamPos);
}

@Override
public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 unused, int width, int height) {
    GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    float ratio = (float) width / height;
    Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
}

public static int loadShader(int type, String shaderCode){

    int shader = GLES20.glCreateShader(type);

    GLES20.glShaderSource(shader, shaderCode);
    GLES20.glCompileShader(shader);

    return shader;
}
}

class Cube {

private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, vBuff2, vBuff3;
private int mPositionHandle;
private int mColorHandle;
private int mMVPMatrixHandle;
private int vertexCount;
private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4;
private float mSpaticalExtent[];

static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;
static float triangleCoords[];
static float sides[];
static float topbottom[];

float color[] = { 0.93671875f, 0.46953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };
float color2[] = { 0.43671875f, 0.96953125f, 0.22265625f, 1.0f };
float color3[] = { 0.33671875f, 0.46953125f, 0.82265625f, 1.0f };

public Cube() {

    MakeCube(0, 0, 0, 10);


    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            triangleCoords.length * 4);
    bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
    vertexBuffer.put(triangleCoords);
    vertexBuffer.position(0);


    ByteBuffer bb2 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            sides.length * 4);
    bb2.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vBuff2 = bb2.asFloatBuffer();
    vBuff2.put(sides);
    vBuff2.position(0);


    ByteBuffer bb3 = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
            topbottom.length * 4);
    bb3.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    vBuff3 = bb3.asFloatBuffer();
    vBuff3.put(topbottom);
    vBuff3.position(0);
}

private void MakeCube(float x, float y, float z, float width) {
    triangleCoords = new float[(int)width*(int)width*6]; // Width * Width * 6 Points * 3 Float per point
    sides = new float[(int)width*(int)width*6];
    topbottom = new float[(int)width*(int)width*6];

    vertexCount = triangleCoords.length / COORDS_PER_VERTEX;
    mSpaticalExtent = new float[1];
    mSpaticalExtent[0] = width;
    x -= width/2f;
    y -= width/2f;
    z -= width/2f;
    int currentArrayPoint = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // FRONT AND BACK WALLS- X AND Y CHANGE Z DOESN'T
            //
            triangleCoords[currentArrayPoint++] = (x + j) / width;
            triangleCoords[currentArrayPoint++] = (y + i) / width;
            triangleCoords[currentArrayPoint++] = z / width;
            //
            triangleCoords[currentArrayPoint++] = (x + j) / width;
            triangleCoords[currentArrayPoint++] = (y + i) / width;
            triangleCoords[currentArrayPoint++] = (z + width) / width;
        }
    }
    currentArrayPoint = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // SIDE WALLS, Y AND Z CHANGE X DOESN'T
            //
            sides[currentArrayPoint++] = x / width;
            sides[currentArrayPoint++] = (y + i) / width;
            sides[currentArrayPoint++] = (z + j) / width;
            //
            sides[currentArrayPoint++] = (x + width) / width;
            sides[currentArrayPoint++] = (y + i) / width;
            sides[currentArrayPoint++] = (z + j) / width;
        }
    }
    currentArrayPoint = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            // TOP AND BOTTOM WALLS, X AND Z CHANGE Y DOESN'T
            //
            topbottom[currentArrayPoint++] = (z + j) / width;
            topbottom[currentArrayPoint++] = (y) / width;
            topbottom[currentArrayPoint++] = (x + i) / width;
            //
            topbottom[currentArrayPoint++] = (z + j) / width;
            topbottom[currentArrayPoint++] = (y + width) / width;
            topbottom[currentArrayPoint++] = (x + i) / width;
        }
    }
}

public void draw(int mProgram, float[] mvpMatrix, float[] mCamPos) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
    int mCamHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vCamPos");
    GLES20.glUniform3fv(mCamHandle, 1, mCamPos, 0);


    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);
    int mSpaticalHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vSpatical");
    GLES20.glUniform1fv(mSpaticalHandle, 1, mSpaticalExtent, 0);
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);



    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vBuff2);
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color2, 0);
    mSpaticalHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vSpatical");
    GLES20.glUniform1fv(mSpaticalHandle, 1, mSpaticalExtent, 0);
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);



    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
            mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
            vertexStride, vBuff3);
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");
    GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color3, 0);
    mSpaticalHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vSpatical");
    GLES20.glUniform1fv(mSpaticalHandle, 1, mSpaticalExtent, 0);
    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, vertexCount);


    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
}
}
```

Comment: Well, `"  gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix;"` is completely wrong for OpenGL. It should be: `"  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;"` (column-major post-multiplication). I checked the code you use to send your MVP matrix, and it does not transpose the matrix, so your shader is what is backwards.

Comment: Brilliant, fixed my problem! I can't believe I made such a stupid mistake. If you want to post your comment as an 'answer' I'll accept it as being correct. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### After looking at your shaders, I noticed the following:

```
gl_Position = vPosition * uMVPMatrix; // D3D convention
```

This is completely wrong for OpenGL (which uses *column-major* matrices and *post-multiplication*).

#### It should be:

```
gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition; // OpenGL convention
```

I checked the code you use to send your MVP matrix, and it does not transpose the matrix, so your shader is what is backwards.

You could also solve this by setting the `transpose` parameter in `GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv` to **true**, but it is best to stick with traditional OpenGL convention and use column-major matrices. It is much easier to diagnose these sorts of things if you do.